# CustomInterceptor to intercept @UpdateProvider linked method,but execute twice

Tags: java, mybatis, interceptor

I defined an interceptor to intercept the update method.The method body only prints the intercepted SQL.

The SQL is constructed through the buildupdatesql () method in @ updateprovider and internally created using "org. Apache. Ibatis. JDBC. SQL".

But the buildoupdatesql () method was executed twice.

The effect is shown in the figure below:

[image]

**MyBatis version**

3.5.7

**Database vendor and version**

MySQL 5.7.34-log

**Expected result**

buildUpdateSql() method only execute once.

**Actual result**

buildUpdateSql() method execute twice.

**Kernel Code**

```java
@Repository
public interface UserMapper  {
    List<User> Sel();
    @UpdateProvider(type = UserMapperProvider.class, method = "buildUpdateSql")
    public int updateSubSite(int id);
    public static class UserMapperProvider{
        public String buildUpdateSql(int id) {
            String sql = "update user set name='gfgfgfg' where id=#{id}";
            System.out.println("构造的sql时："+sql);
            return sql;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Intercepts({ @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "update", args = { MappedStatement.class, Object.class }) })
public class CustomInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private Properties properties;
    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        MappedStatement mappedStatement = (MappedStatement) invocation.getArgs()[0];
        String sql = mappedStatement.getBoundSql(invocation.getArgs()[1]).getSql();
        System.out.println("获取到SQL语句：" + sql);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class MybatisConfig {
@Autowired
  private List<SqlSessionFactory> sqlSessionFactoryList;
   @PostConstruct
   public void addMySqlInterceptor() {
       CustomInterceptor interceptor = new CustomInterceptor();
       for (SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory : sqlSessionFactoryList) {
           sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().addInterceptor(interceptor);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @guofan Do those `SqlSessionFactory`s use different `Configuration`? If you shared one `Configuration`, the same interceptor is registered multiple times, I guess.

Comment: @ave It has nothing to do with configuration.
I try to delete MybatisConfig.java and modify CustomInterceptor.java and add Component annotation, but the console will still print

1. 构造的sql时：update user set name='gfgfgfg' where id=#{id}
2. 获取到SQL语句：update user set name='gfgfgfg' where id=?
3. 构造的sql时：update user set name='gfgfgfg' where id=#{id}